# In sitecore 6.6 Lucene how to match the HitScores.Scores against the SearchResultCollection

Tags: sitecore, lucene.net

In sitecore 6.6  Lucene how to match the HitScores.Scores against the SearchResultCollection and add it to the SearchResultCollection and access the SearchResultCollection later with its scores.

```
public static SearchResultCollection Search(string searchString, IndexSearchContext context){

Hits hitScores = context.Searcher.Search(completeQuery, new Sort(new SortField[1] { SortField.FIELD_SCORE }));

 SearchHits hits = new SearchHits(hitScores);
SearchResultCollection results = hits.FetchResults(0, Int32.MaxValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it:

```
var collector = Lucene.Net.Search.TopScoreDocCollector.create(NumberOfHits, true);
context.Searcher.Search(query, collector);
totalResults = collector.GetTotalHits();
if (totalResults <= 0)
{
    return null;
}
var resultCollection = collector.TopDocs(firstDocument, lastDocument);
IList<Document> docs = new List<Document>(totalResults);
foreach (var tdoc in resultCollection.ScoreDocs)
{
    //tdoc.doc
    //tdoc.score
    Document d = context.Searcher.Doc(tdoc.doc); //Here you have 2 objects
   // tdoc contains the score and d the full document.
    docs.Add(d);
}
```

I hope it helps!